# Blackberry persistent store - no data saved after handheld restart

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, persistent-storage

I'm trying to write an app for blackberries and I'm using the persistent store, but when I restart the device, the data is lost. Anyone's got any clue why this is happening?
thanks in advance to everyone!

`public static void add(Subscription s) throws IOException {
        Vector subscriptions = SubscriptionsController.getSubscriptions();
        if(subscriptions == null) subscriptions = new Vector();
        subscriptions.addElement(s);
        synchronized(SubscriptionsController.persistedSubscriptions) {
            SubscriptionsController.persistedSubscriptions.setContents(subscriptions);
            SubscriptionsController.persistedSubscriptions.commit();
        }
    }`

Comment: please post the code you're using

Comment: @seand, the code i posted above does the actual saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming (always a bad idea lol) that you have subclassed PersistentStore /PersistentObject (since you can commit(), etc)?
Did you implement Persistable (it is not inherited by subclasses)?

Comment: Hi Dan. That was exactly my problem. I was persisting a vector of Subscriptions objects which didn't implement the Persistable interface. Now it's working :)

Comment: Love that CrackBerry  :)
Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

SubscriptionsController isn't a Blackberry class as far as I am aware. It looks like your unexpected behaviour is due to the implementation of this class.

If you wish to persist object state across device resets, you need to use the [PersistentStore](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/index.html) API which serialises objects to a file on the Blackberry. [This document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Working_with_the_persistent_store_1253892_11.jsp) on RIM's site explains use of the `PersistentStore`

Comment: SubscriptionsController is a class I have created, where persistedSubscriptions is declared as a static variable. The data is persisted the first time (a vector of Subscription objects), but when I restart, they're deleted.

Comment: Static variables are not persisted over blackberry restarts. If you wish to persist objects, you need the PersistentStore api. I've edited my response to say this.